# wordpress phpMyAdmin database integration best practices

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a financial website on localhost to provide income reporting on share portfolios using phpMyAdmin wordpress, wpDataTables and before I migrate the system to the web, I want to ensure the structure of the my databases follows best practice.

I currently have 2 databases defined namely

```
**dividendmanager**
portfolios
transactions
stocks etc.

**wordpress**
wp_ tables ..
```

I am considering copying the dividendmanager tables to the wordpress database using phpMyAdmin changing the table names as follows :-

portfolios becomes say **wp_dm1234_portfolios**  etc.

1. is this a better approach than holding 2 databases ?

   I assume that in copying I should 
   check Add AUTO_INCREMENT value to maintain next id value in sequence

   a.check Add constraints

   b.check Adjust Privileges

   c.switch to copied table 
   is not required until I change all my queries in wpDataTables to point to the new table ??

Then when migrating to the web I can just migrate the one database **wordpress** and change its name and the wp_ prefix to improve the security.

Thanks for any help

Colin

Comment: I mean you're using WP - not best practice in terms or security xD but IMO all tables used by a site should be in one database. Just use $wpdb->prefix in your code when referencing new tables made by your modules. You could change prefix but honestly, if they have your db deets, what's a prefix change going to do? The only thing it could possibly protect from, is SQL injection - but if your code uses prepared statements, than this isn't an issue

Comment: Thanks for comments, good ideas, re SQL Injection, I would have to ask whether wpDataTables uses prepared statements in its resulting code, I'll take a look at the PHP files of the plugin

Comment: it's always best to find out, plugins tend to be WP's biggest security flaw

Comment: I'll do that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single database with multiple tables. It will be easier to manage. I don't recommend adding `wp_` to tables which are not related to WordPress. Instead, you can have something like:

```
dm_portfolios
dm_transactions
dm_stocks etc.
wp_posts etc.
```

I'm not entirely sure if you are accessing these Dividend Manager tables using WordPress. If you are, then you can also consider `wp_dm_`.

For security of WordPress, be sure to use a security plugin like WordFence (I'm not affiliated with them in any way).

Comment: Thanks Alec, that's good advice I will start the transfer of my tables on that basis Cheers Colin

Comment: I am accessing the Dividend Manager tables using MySQL via the wpDataTables plugin within wordpress